# Can't get comment scope

Tags: php, api, instagram, instagram-api

I am working with the Instagram API and want to get permission to post comments on behalf of the users. But somehow it does not work.

The request link:

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&response_type=token&scope=comments+likes
```

When this link is going to be opened, I get asked to give permission for basic information and liking, but not for commenting...
[image: Where is the comment scope?]

And now after I give permission and want to add a comment with the API, it returns a 400 error:

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthPermissionsException","code":400,"error_message":"This request requires scope=comments, but this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=comments to be granted write permissions."}}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it not possible to get the comments scope? I do it like Instagram describes it on this link on the very bottom
[Instagram Authentication](https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you complete the following form?

https://help.instagram.com/contact/185819881608116

It looks like you must complete the form before your app will have access to the POST comments endpoint.